# Hide a quiz question until previous one is answered using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

So I made a quiz using html and now I have to use php script to make the quiz function such that there is only question available and once that question is answered, the next question will pop up. So when the user starts up the quiz only the first question will pop up and then when answered, the second will pop up. And then after the last one.I included my html code down below. And my php script. Is the php script headed towards the right path, if not, what am I doing wrong and how would I fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test your Math Skills!</title>
  <link href ="style.css" rel ="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="question-container" class="hide">
          <h1><center><u> Are You Smarter Than A Fifth Grader? 
 </center></h1></u>
        <img id = "image" src = "Photos/gameLogo.jpg" style = "width:400px;height:300px;">
          </div>

<form action="script.php" method="post">

<p class = "questions">What ocean is Japan apart of?</p>

<input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "Arctic"> Arctic<br>
<input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "Pacific"> Pacific<br>
<input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "Atlantic"> Atlantic<br>
<input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "Indian"> Indian<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />

<p id = "question2" style = display:none> How many feet are in a mile?<br>
<input type = "radio" name = "q2" value = "1280"> 1280<br>
<input type = "radio" name = "q2" value = "3280"> 3280<br>
<input type = "radio" name = "q2" value = "2280"> 2280<br>
<input type = "radio" name = "q2" value = "5280"> 5280<br> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" />

<p id = "question3" style = display:none> What is something that is always arriving but never comes? <br>
<input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "q3">
<input type="submit" name="submit" />

</form>
</html>
</body>
```

This is the script:

```
 if ($_POST['submit'] )  
 {

   echo $question2;

  }

 ?>
```

Comment: Why the `javascript` tag?

Comment: `echo $question2;` < that won't echo anything but an error about it being undefined. Is that what you tried because you don't know what else to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

script.php:

```
<?php
$show_q2 = false;
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['q1'])){
    //Process question
    $show_q2 = true;
}

?>

<form action="script.php" method="post">
<?php if(!$show_q2):?>
   <p class = "questions">What ocean is Japan apart of?</p>

   <input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "Arctic"> Arctic<br>
   <input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "Pacific"> Pacific<br>
   <input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "Atlantic"> Atlantic<br>
   <input type = "radio" name = "q1" value = "Indian"> Indian<br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" />
<?php else: ?>
   <p id = "question2"> How many feet are in a mile?<br>
   <input type = "radio" name = "q2" value = "1280"> 1280<br>
   <input type = "radio" name = "q2" value = "3280"> 3280<br>
   <input type = "radio" name = "q2" value = "2280"> 2280<br>
   <input type = "radio" name = "q2" value = "5280"> 5280<br> 
   <input type="submit" name="submit" />
<?php endif; ?>
<p id = "question3" style = display:none> What is something that is always arriving but never comes? <br>
<input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "q3">
<input type="submit" name="submit" />

</form>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So just to clarify would that be just one file which would be index.php?

Comment: This is an example of one file. If you need to use `processing` file then it is better to use `session` to store some `flags` on answered questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this approach:**

Your answers would be stored in 'choices' session (var_dump($_SESSION['choices'])).

```
<?php @session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['clear'])){
        if(isset($_SESSION['choices'])){ unset($_SESSION['choices']); }
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if(isset($_POST['q']) && trim($_POST['q'])!=""){
            $_SESSION['choices'][]=$_POST['q'];
            header("location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test your Math Skills!</title>
  <link href ="style.css" rel ="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="question-container" class="hide">
          <h1><center><u> Are You Smarter Than A Fifth Grader? 
 </center></h1></u>
        <img id = "image" src = "Photos/gameLogo.jpg" style = "width:400px;height:300px;">
          </div>

<form action="script.php" method="post">
<?php if(count(@$_SESSION['choices'])==0){?>
    <p class = "questions">What ocean is Japan apart of?</p>
    <br/>
    <input type = "radio" name = "q" value = "Arctic"> Arctic<br>
    <input type = "radio" name = "q" value = "Pacific"> Pacific<br>
    <input type = "radio" name = "q" value = "Atlantic"> Atlantic<br>
    <input type = "radio" name = "q" value = "Indian"> Indian<br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
<?php }elseif(count(@$_SESSION['choices'])==1){?>
    <p id = "question2"> How many feet are in a mile?</p>
    <br/>
    <input type = "radio" name = "q" value = "1280"> 1280<br>
    <input type = "radio" name = "q" value = "3280"> 3280<br>
    <input type = "radio" name = "q" value = "2280"> 2280<br>
    <input type = "radio" name = "q" value = "5280"> 5280<br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
<?php }elseif(count(@$_SESSION['choices'])==2){?>
    <p id = "question3"> What is something that is always arriving but never comes? </p>
    <br/>
    <input id = "textbox" type = "text" name = "q">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
<?php }else{?>
<br/>
<br/>
Result:
<hr/>
<?php foreach($_SESSION['choices'] as $key=>$choice){?>
    <div><?php echo $key+1; ?> = <?php echo $choice; ?> 
    <?php if(
        ($key==0 && $choice=="Pacific") 
//      || ($key==1 && $choice=="Q2 ANSWER") 
//      || ($key==2 && $choice=="Q3 ANSWER") 
    ){ echo "(Correct!)"; }else{ echo "(Wrong!)"; }?>
    </div>
<?php }?>
<br/>
<br/>
<?php } ?>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="clear" value="Restart" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The quiz was able to load up with no issue yet when I click submit, the next question does not appear.

Comment: I just updated the code to prevent multiple and blank submission for the same question and tested it to be ok on my end. Try it again. @HamzahN

Comment: The issue still occurs on my end for some reason. When I click restart and or submit, the blank white screen appears for some reason.

Comment: Copy my entire code and replace yours or create a new file and paste then change the form action. There is no reason for it not to work. @HamzahN

Comment: Using `@` is a bad idea, especially during testing. It's an error suppressor.

Comment: All of the radio buttons have the same names; they need to be separated into 2 different groups.

Comment: You're welcome @HamzahN I just added the Result Aspect. It is left for you to check if the answer is correct or not. e.g `if(@$_SESSION['choices'][0]=="Pacific")` to check if the answer to the first question == Pacific. Don't forget to mark this as the right answer and upvote.

Comment: It worked!!!! Thank you soooo much! I just have one question. How would I get it to display, "Correct" after the user gets the question right and then the next question pops up or " Wrong answer, the answer was such " if the user gets it wrong and then allow the next question to pop up right after.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner using @ is very necessary because `$_SESSION['choices']` is not always set.

Comment: @HamzahN The latest update includes answer validation :-) copy and test, then practice. Don't forget to mark and upvote. Happy coding!